# f.readlines() won't return any values

Tags: python, file, text, return, return-value

So I was reading over the Python Documentation/Tutorial, specifically I was looking at the Input/Output with files. This is what the tutorial says will return whatevers in the file:

```
>>> f.readline()
'This is the first line of the file.\n'
>>> f.readline()
'Second line of the file\n'
>>> f.readline()
''
```

I put the same thing in my .py and it didn't return any exceptions or issues, but it didn't return any values, either. This is my code:

```
f = open('test.txt')

f.readlines()
```

Unless I use the variables and a `print`, the program will not return anything thats in the file. Heres my files contents:

```
Hello This Is Test
For Loops In Files
Flying Away
A Bird also Flies
Wow
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working? I think its my interpreter, as I am using SublimeREPL, but it hasn't been doing anything weird before then so I am not too sure. Also, when I try running it in my Python console, it gives me an error, then just closes the console so I can't even see the error. Pretty counter-productive.

Just to clarify, my issue is not the `for` loop, the `for` loop already worked fine from before. The issue is that `f.readlines()` does not return any lines, even though the documentation says it should return the next line. I will take the `for` loop out of my code to clarify. Also, sorry if I am mixing up `f.readline()` and `f.readlines()`, but they both don't work, anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo, but `readlines()` reads ALL lines of a file. You've been mixing `readline` and `readlines` for a while now.

Comment: Are you executing those statements at the shell prompt?

Comment: @wwii No, I am using SublimeREPL, a Sublime Text 2/3 interpreter plugin. It has been working well with pretty much everything, even modules that didn't come with Python, so I don't think its REPL. Also, when I do run the .py file in Command Prompt, it gives me an error but just closes out too fast for me to see.

Comment: ```file.readline()``` *returns* a line.  If the statement is executed at the Python shell prompt (as shown in the Tutorial examples) the returned value will be displayed.  If the statements are being run in a script then then you must ```print``` the returned value for it to be displayed on (sent to) ```stdout```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file line by line, this would be a better option.  The 'for line in f:' iterates over the file as a list.  The 'line' variable includes the trailing '\n' or '\r\n', so you'll want to strip those.

The 'with' statement ensures that the file is closed even if your program throws an exception when reading the file.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
Hello This Is Test
For Loops In Files
Flying Away
A Bird also Flies
Wow
```

Using readlines:

```
open('test.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

readlines turns the file into a list in memory.  It isn't efficient if you have to read a large file.

Using both:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
    print
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
Hello This Is Test

For Loops In Files
Flying Away
A Bird also Flies
Wow
```

From python console:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('test.txt')
>>> f.readlines()
['Hello This Is Test\n', 'For Loops In Files\n', 'Flying Away\n', 'A Bird also Flies\n', 'Wow\n', '\n']
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: It must be something in your environment.  Perhaps the path that Sublime is shelling out to run the shell isn't the correct directory.  Try running the program from the command line and see if it works then.

Comment: If I try to open the file I get: `IOError: [Errno: 22] invalid mode 'r' or file or filename`. I am running Python 2.7.8.

Comment: Your open statement does not include the 'r'   to set the file mode to read.

Comment: I had the same problem as I was opening a file with "a+".  It is fixed if you open with "r" instead.

Comment: in my case, the file was opened in another process, and the lines came empty. After f.close(), i can read the file.

Answer (score 5):

I've figured out an answer to a very similar issue in case someone comes here looking. So in Python if you have ran code of `readline()` prior to `readlines()` then it has already iterated through those lines.

Try exiting out and ONLY typing `readlines()` for a file and it will make the full list for you.

Answer (score 1):

f.readlines() returns all the lines at once inside a list, for your example:

```
f=open('test.txt')
f.readlines()
['Hello This Is Test\n', 'For Loops In Files\n', 'Flying Away\n', 'A Bird also Flies\n', 'Wow']
```

as for f.readline() will return the lines one by one starting from where the cursor is untill the end of the file, your example output will be:

```
f=open('test.txt')
f.readline()
'Hello This Is Test\n'
f.readline()
'For Loops In Files\n'
f.readline()
'Flying Away\n'
f.readline()
'A Bird also Flies\n'
f.readline()
'Wow'
f.readline()
''#empty string
```

to set the cursor to the beginning of the file use seek(0)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. That happens because Python is not showing multiple outputs but just one. Import the following and that will solve the problem.

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe the story is like this:

1. You write a code like `file.readline()` but it didn't work as expected
2. To figure out what's happening, you add a debug watch variable in your IntelliJ Idea like `file.readline()` and then you correct your code also as file.readline()
3. Then you re-debug your code. If you have only one single line in the file to be read, then the `file.readline()` will be executed firstly from your watch and then from your source code.

That's why your source code's `file.readline()` cannot get anything.

All in all, not all operation is **idempotent**, your debug watch may be interfering your source codes' running...

Answer (score -3):

The issue was that when scripting I had to use `print`, but in a command prompt, I can just use `f.readlines()` and it will read the lines.